# android imageSpan mess up when over 2 and 3?

Tags: android

I am a chinese, sorry my english is not very well. 
Here is my Question:
I need implement a function that can show Emoticon in text, i use imageSpan to implement this. i successed to show emoticon but the result is mess up, when have over 2 or 3 images , it just mess up

![enter image description here][1]

can anybody tell my how to fix this? thanks a lot

```
if (getFaceCount() >= 10) {
            if (toast == null)
                toast = new MyToast(context);

            toast.showToast("最多只能添加10个表情    ", 3000);
            break;
        }
        int index = txtContent.getSelectionStart();
        // 插入字符
        Editable editable = txtContent.getText();
        editable.insert(index, v.getTag().toString());
        // 显示表情
        Spannable s = txtContent.getText();

        Drawable d = null;
        try {
            d = getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(
                    new JYCReflection<R.drawable>().getIntField(
                            R.drawable.class, v.getTag().toString()
                                    .replace("[", "").replace("]", "")));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
        d.setBounds(0, 0, JYCScreen.dip2px(20, JYCScreen.scale),
                JYCScreen.dip2px(20, JYCScreen.scale));
        ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d);
        s.setSpan(span, index, index + 6,
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

[Image]http://www.freeimagehosting‘net/t/nfjy1.jpg

Comment: Post some code please.

Comment: i posted please see this

Comment: i can't post image because this website say i need some reputation ....

Comment: i have no choice so i change my head picture to my mess up app image.....

Comment: Can you upload the image to an image server and post the link. The image on your profile is very small.

Comment: Try uploading to this link: http://tinypic.com/

Comment: @Andres http://i40.tinypic.com/2zpi6x4.png

Comment: I don't see icons messing up on that picture

Comment: @Andres the editText, i want to the emoticon line up, but it's always auto change line, like the pic, it should be one line, but it's three lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d);
```

To:

```
ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
```

---

According to your comment try adding this in your EditText XML file:

```
<EditText 
    android:maxLines = "1"
</EditText>
```

Comment: i know where my problem is , the problem is if input the chinese Character and english character in the same time , textview and edittext will auto change line ,so weird, do you know how to fix this? and thanks for you patient help, wish god bless you